# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function twentytwenty_the_post_meta()

Tags: templates, fatal-error

I'm working with WordPress customization, I created a template who has the following code

```
<?php 
/*
    Template name: Master Template  
*/
get_header();
?>

<body>
    
<?php 
if(have_posts()):
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
endif;
?>
</body>

<?php 
get_footer();
?>
```

I used this template in "Test" page it was working correctly before I removed "Test" page text and add a new one, after adding new text it is showing fatal error. I don't know why it is throwing this error. I tried to remove new added text(added from elementor) and also remove body code but still getting same error.

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> twentytwenty_the_post_meta() in
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/template-parts/entry-header.php:70
> Stack trace: #0
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/template.php(725):
> require() #1
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/template.php(672):
> load_template('/nas/content/li...', false) #2
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/general-template.php(168):
> locate_template(Array, true, false) #3
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/template-parts/content.php(20):
> get_template_part('template-parts/...') #4
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/template.php(725):
> require('/nas/content/li...') #5
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/template.php(672):
> load_template('/nas/content/li...', false) #6
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-includes/general-template.php(168):
> locate_template(Array, true, false) #7
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/singular.php(24
> in
> /nas/content/live/betterworldstg/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/template-parts/entry-header.php
> on line 70

Please help me.

Comment: It should be defined in wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/inc/template-tags.php which gets included by the main theme's functions.php. So either you've edited one of these files or you've lost the file somehow. I'd first try reinstalling a fresh copy of the theme.

Comment: And where is this new template - is it in a child theme? Beware of losing your work if you've modified twentytwenty directly.

Comment: this template is in parent theme, how to handle this in it, if I want to to this?